# SQL Procedure compilation hangs

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I am trying to compile an oracle procedure. It works fine in Database hosted on Windows machine but when I try to deploy this stored procedure with same database copy which is hosted on linux server, compilation never finishes. 
It remains in hanged status.

With this procedure I am updating a table which contains 0 rows.

Can you please let me know what things I need to check to troubleshoot this problem.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Check that no other sessions are holding a lock on that table

Comment: Maybe some session is currently running that stored procedure

Comment: The procedure won't update the table during compilation, only when it's executed.

Comment: Right, but when I comment the UPDATE to the table and compile the procedure, it works fine.   If I uncomment that statement and try to compile, it just hangs.......only this one table.   Other remote tables are updated in the procedure, but just this remote table.......